# Tried compiling a Java Program and received this message

Tags: java, compiler-errors

[image]

I tried compiling my program , it worked fine before, and received the message `Permission Denied`. Is there something I need to change?

Comment: A java source file is not a script. You have to compile it with `javac` and run the class file it generates with `java` This not a compiler error as you are not running the compiler. I suggest using a IDE so you can edit the java file and run it by clicking the Run button.

Comment: It almost looks like you tried to navigate directly into the Java file like it was a directory instead of running the javac compiler command.

Comment: Thank you !!! I am new at Java and it is clearly a Simple Error on behalf

Comment: @takendarkk Thank you , yes I was missing javac /users/javierbolanos/Desktop/Comparable.java